# Can't mount another server in crontab with 16.04

Tags: mount, cron

I have two servers in my network and I transfer some of the data from one server to the other.  I wrote a script to accomplish this and it works fine when I run it manually.  However, when I include it in crontab in order to automate the process, it will not mount the external server even though the script runs.  I send as much info to a log as possible but, no mount errors are reported, just the fact that it did not connect.

This is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE="/var/log/SRV1.log"
echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)"  --- Begins Now" | tee -a ${LOGFILE} 
StartTime="$(date +%s)"
echo "Connecting to SRV1" | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
mount.cifs //192.168.1.200/share /media/SVR1 -o user=username,pass=pwd | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
```

The file is owned by root:root with 755 permissions.  (I know I could tighten that up but, I'm still just experimenting).

Comment: Thank you steeldriver.  Great answer!  The routine now works in cron.

Comment: **Rick**: you should accept @steeldriver answer below the next time you sign on.

Answer (score 5):

The `cron` program runs in a very limited environment - you can see that for example if you create a crontab containing

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /tmp/cronenv
```

and then look at the resulting file:

```
$ cat /tmp/cronenv
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
HOME=/home/steeldriver
LOGNAME=steeldriver
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/steeldriver
```

The same applies to `root` crontabs (i.e. jobs submitted using `sudo crontab -e`):

```
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

In particular, the default `PATH` only contains `/bin` and `/usr/bin`; that would be fine for `mount`:

```
$ which mount
/bin/mount
```

however that won't work for `mount.cifs` for example, since it's in `/usr/sbin`:

```
$ which mount.cifs
/sbin/mount.cifs
```

The solution is either:

1. always use the full absolute path for executable programs in scripts to be run as cron jobs; e.g.

   ```
   /usr/sbin/mount.cifs //192.168.1.200/share /media/SVR1 -o user=username,pass=pwd | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
   ```

or

2. add a suitable `PATH` assignment at the top of such scripts e.g.

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   ```

---

NOTE: Jobs run from the system `/etc/cron.d` directory have a more extensive path set explicitly in `/etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```