# cron shutdown command not working

Tags: shutdown, cron

I want to stop Linux everyday at 01:00 am with cron.

What I tried is: `sudo -i`, `crontab -e` and `00 01 * * * shutdown -h now` in the terminal.

I tried a lot of similar commands like `00 01 * * * poweroff`, but these commands never work. I save the `crontab` with <kbd>ctrl 0 + enter</kbd>, then by doing ctrl X. When I'm about to leave the console, I don't see any errors, I only see that the crontab has been sucessfully installed.

I'm using x2go to access Linux, and i cant login directly as root. When i try to login as root, i have the error:

> ttyname failed inappropriate ioctl for device

When I navigate through my files I noticed that I can't access the root folder because I don't have the permission.

I think the problem may be that I don't have root access but `sudo -i` should give me root access. I also tried enabling root access by entering the command `sudo passwd root` then entering `su root`.

It's my first time using Linux so please don't hesitate to explain with as much as details as possible.

edit: ok, so i found the solution, I just have to set the command one hour before the desired time. I dont know why but it works. Thanks for everyone help.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the cron job is not working? Are you *sure* want to use shutdown's `-h` flag?

Comment: its not working because ive tested it at a different time. Ive used shutdown without -h but the result is the same

Comment: Both `shutdown` and `poweroff` are in `/sbin`, which AFAIK is not in the root cron path. See for example [Can't mount another server in crontab with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/919512/178692)

Comment: ok im looking up your thread, it looks like from what i see that i have to specify the path where is shutdown

Comment: ... yes, so `/sbin/shutdown -h now` for example. Use `type -a shutdown` in the terminal if you're not sure what path to use.

Comment: I entered this cronjob with root access: 49 02 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now, but linux didnt shutdown at 02 49 am( its a test since its the time here)

Answer (score 6):

For security reasons, CRON uses a very minimal shell environment. This includes a minimal PATH and HOME variables. In most cases, you want to use full paths for all commands.

So, I would suggest you first run:

```
$ which shutdown
/sbin/shutdown
```

Now you know the full path to that command and you want to use that in your CRON definition:

```
0 1 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

If you want to add variables to the shell (or need to in order to run certain commands) you can add or update them at the top of the file. For example:

```
PATH=/sbin:${PATH}
HOME=/root

0 1 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Keep in mind that the handling of spaces and tabs is different (see the docs for details).

One variable which is often updated is the `MAILTO=<your-email>`. By default, emails will be sent to `root` for the root account. I prefer to use an alias (often defined in `/etc/aliases`). The alias allows me to send the emails to multiple administrators instead of just one person.

To become root, I use the following:

```
sudo su -
```

which I find cleaner than many other solutions. You can then edit the `crontab` of the root user with:

```
crontab -e
```

As you've shown in your question.

Otherwise, the leading zeroes are *probably* okay. I never put them there and the examples do not show such. Just in case, I would try without them as I've shown above.

For additional info, I would suggest you read the crontab manuals:

```
man crontab
man 5 crontab
```

The first one is about the command line.

The second one is about the file format. They talk about the shell variables. The `PATH`, the `MAILTO`, etc. It's a good read.

Comment: So i did exactly what you told me: - sudo su - , crontab -e and finally 49 02 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now, but linux didnt shutdown at 02 49 am( its a test since its the time here)

Comment: Minor quibble: although cron runs jobs *using* `/bin/sh`, crontabs aren't themselves shell scripts and the crontab syntax *does* allow spaces around `name = value` variable assignments. See `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: More major quibble: I don't expect `PATH=/sbin:${PATH}` will work (*"The value string is not parsed for environmental substitutions or replacement of variables"*)

Comment: I tried this as you suggested in cron: PATH=/sbin:${PATH}, HOME=/root, 45 03 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now

 .Its still not working

Comment: @VincentEscaich Maybe try `+1` instead of `now`. That means it will shutdown one minute later. Also if your root email account is not properly setup, emails are likely to go to a folder such as `/var/mail` or `/var/spool/mail`. Otherwise it may go to `/root/Mail/...`. In any event, when CRON generates an error, assuming it fails running your command, it should send an email and the email should give you information about what to do to fix the problem. Also for the time, please try without the leading zero (i.e. `3` and not `03`).

Comment: i can't access my root mail since i cant access the root folder(because im logged in as user and cant login as root as stated before). Ive been able to see the email of the user account, but theres nothing really interesting in it. I can find things like that on the user's email: /bin/sh: 1: poweroff: not found or / bin/sh: 1: root: not found, but thats normal since i wasnt using the correct path in the command.

Comment: I tried setting up my root email by entering the command: MAILTO={my email} as you suggested. The command was accepted but i never received an email

Comment: And I already tried without the leading zero before but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think the command is excuted but with a lot of delay. For example, I entered `10 16 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now`. So linux should have been shutdown at 4:10 pm. It was not the case. But when I came back almost exactly one hour later(leaving linux open), linux was shutdown. Its weird because linux time is the same as my time.

Comment: @VincentEscaich Oh! That's probably a summer/winter time difference. I sometime have CRON commands run 1h later in the summer.

Comment: Have you tried to `sudo su -` command to become root? If you can use `sudo` you can become root that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try his site
http://cron.schlitt.info
To know if is your command or you time configuration, try also `init 0` (power off) and `init 6` (restart.)

Comment: my time configuration and command configuration is fine according to what you said. For example, to stop linux at 4:10 pm i enter `10 16 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now`. http://cron.schlitt.info/ says that this time configuration (`10 16 * * *`) is fine. And when enter `init 0` as root, linux shutdowns.

Comment: But as ive just stated above, it looks like the command is working but delayed by an hour, although the time configuration of linux is correct (same as my time).

Comment: Hello, create a redirect output to a file, touch file.log sudo chmod 777 file.log sudo crontab -e add ">> /home/user/file.log"  */10 * * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now >> /home/user/file.log this grep CRON /var/log/syslog; Hope that help you.