# Cannot run logrotate utility automatically from cron

Tags: cron, logrotate

I run `sudo crontab -e` and append the following line:

```
* * * * * logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/adraw; touch /ADraw/Data/Logs/test.txt
```

The file test.txt is successfully created, but I see no results of logrotate.
Strangely, if I run `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/adraw` everything works (additional files created).

my `/etc/logrotate.d/adraw` configuration:

```
/ADraw/Data/Logs/*.log {
    hourly
    size 1M
    missingok
    rotate 5
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 ADraw ADraw
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

Comment: At least on my system, `logrotate` is in `/usr/sbin` - which is likely not in cron's default `PATH`. Please try again with the full path `/usr/sbin/logrotate`

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @steeldriver If you don't start posting your comments as answers I might catch up to you in points! **Apogentus** please accept your own answer in two days so it comes off the *unanswered* questions database listing.

Comment: @steeldriver The default path for cron is `/usr/bin` and `/bin` as stated this Q&A: [Where is cron's PATH set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/where-is-crons-path-set) asked by the renowned Terdon and answered by the renowned muru.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix indeed - and as posted by me here [Can't mount another server in crontab with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/919512/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver I've read at least a dozen `crontab` Q&A's here in AU where the absolute path was missing for command. If I were a mod I would write a generic Q&A and close all those Q's as a dupe against it.

Answer (score 5):

As steeldriver said, the solution was to add full path to logrotate in cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/adraw; touch /ADraw/Data/Logs/test.txt
```