# Whats wrong with this cron job?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I set up a `cronjob` to write a webpage every 50 minutes, but when accessing them, the webpages were blank.

The `cronjob`: `50 * * * * mkIndex.sh  > /home/user/img/index.html`.

The `mkIndex.sh` is a script I wrote, in `/home/$USER/bin`, which is in the `$PATH`, running the script in the same way shown in `crontab` seems to work fine, it generates the webpage.

So why is my `index.html` file blank? Alternatively, can you see any flaw in my script?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n"
echo -e "<style>\ndiv.gallery {\nmargin: 1px;\nborder: 1px solid #ccc;\nfloat: left;\n"
echo -e" width: 180px;\n}\n\ndiv.gallery:hover {\nborder: 1px solid #777;\n}\n\ndiv.gallery img {\n"
echo -e "width: 10%;\nheight: auto;\n}\n"
echo -e "</style>\n</head>\n"
echo -e "<body>\n"
 
cd /home/user/img
for i in `ls *.png`
do
echo -e "<div class="gallery">"
echo -e  "<a target="$i" href="$i">"
echo -e   " <img src="$i"  width="300" height="200">"
echo -e  "</a>"
echo -e "</div>"
done
 
echo -e "</body>\n</html>"
```

I'm not sure why my `cronjob` isn't generating the desired output.

Comment: Silly question, but is the cron job set up to run from `root` or from your account?

Comment: omg yeah. Can a non priviliged user run cronjobs?

Comment: so like this then? $crontab -e -u user
50 * * * * user  mkIndex.sh  > /home/user/img/index.html
I'll see how that goes.

Comment: "*Alternatively, can you see any flaw in my shell script?*" ... Yes, :-) ... Parsing the output of `ls` with  `for i in $(ls *.png)` ... please see https://askubuntu.com/a/1446578/968501 for more information ... Plus the back-ticks for command substitution are deprecated in favor of `$( ... )`

Comment: For your original question as @matigo hinted above ... You want to always use the full absolute path to your `mkIndex.sh` script in the cron entry and probably even better provide the full path to the executing shell executable file like `/bin/bash /home/user/mkIndex.sh ...`.

Comment: `/home/$USER/bin` may well be in your PATH in an *interactive* login, but almost certainly is not in cron's PATH. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/919512/178692) for example.

Comment: will running `# run-parts /etc/cron.hourly/` execute the task? or do I need to put a link in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a link to the script in `/bin` where root can use it. That alone did not work, after editing `ctrontab -e`
every way I could imagine, I deleted my entry there, and edited the file `/etc/crontab` to include a line for the script with root as the user.
`50 * * * * root mkIndex.sh  > /home/user/img/index.html`

That worked.